# VBA: Extracting Text from child Div Class within Div Class

Tags: html, vba, text, extract

I have a search page with the structure as below. There are upto 70 instances of **searchRecord** on the page. I need to extract the text denoted by the asterixes *** and put them into separate cells in excel. So each searchrecord would have a new row.

```
<div class="searchRecord">
                <div class="thumb">
                    <a href="**SKU**">
                        <img src="/product_images/.jpg" alt="**Title**" title="**Title**" border="0"  />                        </a>
                </div>
                <div class="desc">
                    <h1><a href="**SKU**">**Title**</a></h1>
                    <p>**Category**</p>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div align="center">
                        <div style="width:30%">
                            <style>.bv_rating{ margin:3px 0px 0px 30px; }</style><div id='BVRRInlineRating-5030917094484' class="bv_rating"></div>                          </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="prodPrice">
                        <div style="padding-top: 6px;">
                            <div class="priceTxt">**Price1**</div>
                            <div class="priceTxt">**Price2**</div><br /><div class="priceTxt">**Price3**</div><br />                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

I need to extract the following:

**SKU**

**Title** (there are 3 possible examples)

**Category**

**Price1**

**Price2**

**Price3**

I've managed to get this working before but only when the main div class has a unique name - can this be done with

```
Set searchres= oHtml.getElementsByClassName("searchRecord")(0).getElementsByTagName("span")
i = 0
For Each oElement In searchres
 Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i + 1) = searchres(i).innerText
 i = i + 1
Next oElement
```

Comment: Will the below get the httpojb successfully? I'm getting access denied on `.send`  `Public Function getURL(tURL As String) As String
    Dim tmpString As String
    Randomize

    Dim URL As String
    Dim XMLHttpRequest As Object
    Dim HTMLdoc As Object
    URL = tURL & "&r=" & Int((99999999 * Rnd()) + 1)

    Set XMLHttpRequest = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    Set HTMLdoc = CreateObject("HTMLFile")

    With XMLHttpRequest
    .Open "GET", URL, False
    .send
    HTMLdoc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    tmpString = .responseText
    End With

    getURL = tmpString

End Function`

Comment: Did you edit the ** into the HMTL?

Comment: The asterixes are not there in the original html I used them to mark the elements I needed to extract..

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! So everywhere you see asterixSKUasterix, for example, you want the actual SKU? The actual attribute value as well as the innerText? Did this come from a public URL btw? The reason I mention it is that I was pondering giving you a CSS based solution in VBA.

Comment: See the comment below the answer for the public URL. It may have changed since 2015 slightly though!! The idea is to scrape the whole site for pricing data and title with sku so I can compare with other sites selling second hand games ...

Answer (score 0):

I do not generally like to offer code without testing it first but since no formal URL was offered the only alternative would be to construct a serviceable web page from the short portion of HTML offered.

```
Dim v As Long, vSKUs As Variant
Dim iDIV As Long, pp As Long
Dim oHtml As Object

'at this point oHtml is the HTML body
With oHtml
    If CBool(.getElementsByClassName("searchRecord").Length) Then
        'there is at least one element with the 'searchRecord' class
        'make room for all of the array elements
        ReDim vSKUs(1 To .getElementsByClassName("searchRecord").Length, 1 To 5)
        For iDIV = 1 To .getElementsByClassName("searchRecord").Length
            With .getElementsByClassName("searchRecord")(iDIV - 1)
                'get the SKU from the anchor, otherwise skip to next
                If CBool(.getElementsBytagName("a").Length) Then
                    With .getElementsBytagName("a")(0)
                        vSKUs(iDIV, 1) = .href
                        'get the title from the anchor's image
                        If CBool(.getElementsBytagName("img").Length) Then
                            vSKUs(iDIV, 2) = .Title
                        End If
                    End With
                    'get up to 3 prices
                    If CBool(.getElementsByClassName("prodPrice").Length) Then
                        For pp = 1 To .getElementsByClassName("prodPrice").Length
                            If pp > 3 Then Exit For  'don't get more than 3
                            vSKUs(iDIV, pp + 2) = .getElementsByClassName("prodPrice")(pp - 1).innertext
                        Next pp
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        Next iDIV
    End If
End With

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("A2").Resize(UBound(vSKUs, 1), UBound(vSKUs, 2)) = vSKUs
End With
```

Hopefully, you can see how the checks for existence using `.Length` works together with iterating through the collections. Remember that the elements in a collection have a 1-based length but a 0-based index; e.g. if there are six div elements with a classname of *searchRecord* then the collection has a `.Length` of **6** but are indexed as **0** through **5**. A `.Length` of **0** indicates that there is nothing in the collection.

Comment: Example URL is `http://uk.webuy.com/search/index.php?page=1&stext=%2A&section=1&sortOn=box_name_asc&refinecat=Xbox+360+Games`